# Unable to write data from Spark to Azure Blob Storage - generic Microsoft error message

Tags: apache-spark, azure-storage

Getting a generic Microsoft error **'`Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: One of the request inputs is not valid.`'** when using park-shell to write data to Azure Storage blob.

I am using Spark 2.4.4 (2.7 Hadoop Distribution) distribution and copied the following 2 Azure specific files to **$SPARK_INSTALL_HOME/jars** folder:

- hadoop-azure-2.7.3.jar
- azure-storage-7.0.0.jar

Connect to spark shell after copying azure specific files:
*> bin/spark-shell --jars jars/hadoop-azure-2.7.3.jar,jars/azure-storage-7.0.0.jar*

Create Spark Context along with appropriate Hadoop configuration parameters:

```
scala> sc
scala> sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")
scala> sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.azure.account.key.ACCOUNT_NAME.blob.core.windows.net", "ACCOUNT_KEY")*
```

Read data from Azure Blob storage successfully:

```
scala> val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema", "true").load("wasbs://CONTAINER_NAME@ACCOUNT_NAME.blob.core.windows.net/public_datasets/orders")*

scala> df.show()
+-----+----+---+--------+------+---------+                                      
|  _c0| _c1|_c2|     _c3|   _c4|      _c5|
+-----+----+---+--------+------+---------+
|31614|1499| EF|54662084|3666.0|Household|
|31615|1500| GH| 4727745|4119.0|Household|
|31616|1501| OP|40921163|2292.0|Household|
|31617|1502| IJ|11066508|7338.0|Household|
|31618|1503| OP|11958569|3171.0|Household|
|31619|1504| UV|29212069| 619.0|Household|
|31620|1504| WX|69836336|4887.0|         |
|31621|1506| UV|28518402|9498.0|     Loan|
|31622|1507| ST|  156510|6619.0|Household|
|31623|1508| OP|10600459|1657.7|  Leasing|
|31624|1508| UV| 9055811|8967.0|Household|
|31625|1509| EF|43322950|4943.0|Household|
|31626|1509| QR|20525896|2320.0|         |
|31627|1510| OP|82537191|9985.0|Household|
|31628|1511| OP|43543106|1657.7|  Leasing|
|31629|1512| YZ|42362171|8822.0|Household|
|31630|1513| AB|52238965|1632.0|Household|
|31631|1513| QR|85800695|3912.0|         |
|31632|1513| OP|59476637|1316.0|Insurance|
|31633|1513| GH|65290647| 689.0|         |
+-----+----+---+--------+------+---------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Write data back to a different location:

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").csv("wasbs://CONTAINER_NAME@ACCOUNT_NAME.blob.core.windows.net/public_datasets/orders_modified/")
```

The following exception is being thrown:

```
   Error committing the output of task: attempt_20200608142341_0006_m_000000_8
   org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: One of the request inputs is not valid.
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.rename(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2482)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem$FolderRenamePending.execute(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:424)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.rename(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1997)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:531)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:502)
       at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.performCommit$1(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:50)
       at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.commitTask(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:77)
       at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitTask(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:225)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.commit(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:78)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:247)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:242)
       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1394)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:248)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
   Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: One of the request inputs is not valid.
       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:89)
       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.StorageRequest.materializeException(StorageRequest.java:305)
       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:175)
       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.startCopy(CloudBlob.java:883)
       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.startCopyFromBlob(CloudBlob.java:825)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.StorageInterfaceImpl$CloudBlobWrapperImpl.startCopyFromBlob(StorageInterfaceImpl.java:399)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.rename(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2449)
       ... 22 more
   20/06/08 14:23:45 ERROR Utils: Aborting task
   org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: One of the request inputs is not valid.
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.rename(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2482)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem$FolderRenamePending.execute(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:424)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.rename(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1997)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:531)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:502)
       at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.performCommit$1(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:50)
       at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.commitTask(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:77)
       at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitTask(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:225)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.commit(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:78)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:247)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:242)
       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1394)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:248)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
   Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: One of the request inputs is not valid.
       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:89)
       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.StorageRequest.materializeException(StorageRequest.java:305)
       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:175)
       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.startCopy(CloudBlob.java:883)
       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.startCopyFromBlob(CloudBlob.java:825)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.StorageInterfaceImpl$CloudBlobWrapperImpl.startCopyFromBlob(StorageInterfaceImpl.java:399)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.rename(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2449)
       ... 22 more
```

Any suggestions to get past this problem will be highly appreciated?

Comment: Please try to use `df.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").save(path)`.

Comment: I had already tried the suggestion you made before posting on this forum. I get the same error. Upon further analysis after logging into my Azure Storage account, I see temporary folder '_$azuretmpfolder$' and an empty output folder. The root cause of the problem seems to be copy operation being carried out behind the scene by Azure as reflected in original error message

Comment: I have the same exact issue, did you solve it?